# What is the difference in uniform_int_distribution <> and <int>?

Tags: c++, int, std, distribution, uniform

I am a beginer for C++. I would like to ask that:

is `std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);` equal to `std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(1,6);` ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I correct the writing mistake.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), `std::uniform_int_distribution` has default template argument. It defaults to `int`. Therefore, the following uses are equivalent:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(1, 6);
```

---

The exact definition of this class looks like tihs:

```
template< class IntType = int >
class uniform_int_distribution;
```

`IntType` should be one of `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Then, std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6); is not euqal to std::uniform_int_distribution<long> dis(1, 6)?

Comment: @Fan That's correct (if your _being not equal_ means _having different types_). `long` is guaranteed by the Standard to be a different type from `int` (though both may have the same bit width).

Comment: @DanielLangr So  `std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6)`,  `std::uniform_int_distribution< int> dis(1, 6)`,  `std::uniform_int_distribution< long long> dis(1, 6)` have same effect? They all generate random integer from [1, 6]?

Comment: @Fan I don't know what do you mean by _same effect_. What effect? Anyway, `operator()` of `uniform_int_distribution` returns a value of type `result_type`, which is `IntType` (template parameter). Therefore, for `<int>`, the operator returns a value of type `int`. For `<long>`, it returns a value of type `long`. Which is different. Whether it matters depends on the use of such distribution. As you write, all the versions generate random integers from [1,6], however, they are of generally different types.